# Tough fungus on wall, ready to paint or not?

Tags: walls, painting, cleaning, mold, fungus

[image]

I have a house with fungus on the walls as the roof was leaking and the house was empty for a while and not ventilated. I am fixing the roof. However, I'm cleaning the fungus / mold from the walls but this is very difficult. I doubt whether it is good enough to be able to paint.

I thoroughly treated all the walls with fungus or mold in the bedroom (15m2, approx. 2.3 meters high) with a firm brush and bleach solution. And also in some places with HG and Bison antifungal cleaner. I have treated the wall three times now but I cannot remove the brown colour. The sharp dots are gone but the brown haze remains (see photos). If I scrub very hard, it diminishes slightly, but it remains visible.

What would you do with these walls? Can I paint yet? Or do I have to treat first?When I sand the stains, the white of the wall below shows up (see white part in photo). It looks like I could sand the stains off the wall. Now I'm unsure whether I should do that as sanding can also cause you to rub the dirt deeper into the spot.

And do I perhaps need a construction dryer? I have used about 10 liters of water each time, part of which has been absorbed by the wall. I have now let it ventilate for a few days so that it can dry.

Thanks for the help!

See photos here

[image]

[image]

Comment: please paste the pictures into the question... use the button that looks like the moon and mountains

Comment: What are your walls covered with? In the US (and other places) it might be drywall/plasterboard/similar, which would probably be much easier to remove & replace than it would be to clean.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the links and added photos here.

Comment: I believe the walls are plaster. The are definitely not board or drywall.